# Error in Symfont 2.8 - Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface

Tags: symfony, caching, redeclare, symfony2-easyadmin

Can you help me in this question ...
I use **Symfont 2.8** with **EasyAdminBundle**. 
I was used this manual to install - [symfony2-admin-panel-in-30-seconds](https://level7systems.co.uk/en/symfony2-admin-panel-in-30-seconds/).

Admin panel works fine, but when I try to create my (not-admin) class, I get an error : **Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface in /var/www/html/Legendcorp/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 6568**

For example: I created the class in /src/AppBundle/Controller/APIController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;



class FormController extends BaseAdminController{
    /**
     * @Route("/form/save", name="save")
     */
    public function formAction(Request $request){

    }

}
```

but when I try to apply to this class, I get an error. -

- `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface in /var/www/html/Legendcorp/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 6568`

If I clear the cache (**rm -rf app/cache/***), it will works, **but only as long as you do not contact the admin panel.**

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "files": [ "app/AppKernel.php" ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3@dev",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^0.14.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Please, can you help me?

Comment: If I extends from (class APIController extends Controller) - use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

This is do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The blog post you followed is very nice, but for things like installing the bundle, I always recommend to follow the official documentation. In this case: [Chapter 1. Installation](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/getting-started/1-installation.md) from EasyAdmin's docs.

Regarding the `ContainerAwareInterface` error, I'd say that it has nothing to do with the bundle. We don't use that interface anywhere and we don't use the `ContainerAware` class either. If you remove the bundle, does the Symfony application work without errors?

Comment: I have not tried to remove EasyAdmin. If I do not appeal to the administrative panel, my class is working properly. But if I spend any or manipulation with EasyAdmin, and then I try to apply to my (separate class), - it fails. Could this be a conflict of versions?